# What's a more affordable hosting option for a Java/JDO app built on (the formerly free) App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, hosting, jdo

Because of the price hike announced yesterday for App Engine, it has gone from being an essentially free hosting option to a potentially unaffordable one.

As a result I would like to consider what my options are for migrating my Java/JDO app off App Engine to some other hosting provider.

Because JDO abstracts the underlying database layer, am I correct that a few SQL (GQL) changes and some minor configuration changes (`appengine-web.xml`) are all that would be required to move to some other Java hosting platform?

And, secondly, what other Java hosting platforms offer a similar level of performance for a lower price than the new App Engine price structure?

Comment: Here's a link to the new pricing: http://www.google.com/enterprise/appengine/appengine_pricing.html. Official description: http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/05/year-ahead-for-google-app-engine.html Feedback:

Comment: Can't help on the hosting provider, but obviously DataNucleus provides JDO persistence to a large range of datastores, from RDBMS, ODBMS, documents, map-based and web-based, and some others (e.g LDAP). All should require very minimal changes to any code, and only then to remove non-portable impositions placed on you by GAE/J.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a low or mid price Xen VPS.

Comment: Agreed. Make sure (as Jonas said) that it is Xen (or KVM) though. OpenVZ and similar do not play well with Java.